# yii2 assign non-standard date to model attribute

Tags: date, yii2, variable-assignment, date-format

I have a text file. In this text file, there is a date in the format: dd.mm.yyyy. I would like to upload this file, and then assign its content (the date) to a model attribute which is: a date, and then save to db. I have tried `formatter->asDate`, with a lot of different settings, but I simply couldn't find the right setting or function what would properly recognize this date and change it according to db in order to be able to save it properly.

```
public function assign() {
    $this->date = $this->contentUploadedFile[0]);
    ...
```

I hope it's more clear now. Please help me find the way to achieve this - thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Kindly review it and use example of what you have in the plain text, whats in the db and what you want to archive. As of Yii2 create_at and modified are attached to a behavior event 'before_insert' and 'before_update'. Clarify exactly what you need would be glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting date as a string the file read.
If $this->contentUploadedFile[0] is returning the content of the from, then no need to use "file_get_contents" function. Just place "$this->contentUploadedFile[0]" in strtotime function like below.

```
  $this->date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->contentUploadedFile[0]));
```

Or If "$this->contentUploadedFile[0]" is your file, then read the content of that file. and use below function.

```
$this->date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime(file_get_contents($this->contentUploadedFile[0])));
```

Then you can save the date in the database.